# python: How to clean the csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am a beginner user of Python and would like to clean the csv file for analysis purpose. However, I am facing the problem with the code.

```
def open_dataset(file_name):
    opened_file = open(file_name)
    read_file = reader(opened_file, delimiter=",")
    data = list(read_file)

    return data


def column(filename):
    filename = open_dataset(filename)

    for row in filename:
        print(row)
```

with the code above, the output is like

```
['Name;Product;Sales;Country;Website']
[';Milk;30;Germany;something.com']
[';;;USA;']
['Chris;Milk;40;;']
```

I would like to have the output following:

```
['Name','Product','Sales','Country','Website']
[NaN,'Milk','30','Germany','something.com']
[NaN,NaN,NaN,'USA',NaN]
['Chris','Milk',40,NaN,NaN]
```

I defined a delimiter as "," but still ";" used. I don't know why it is happening. Also Even if I tried to replace the space with "NaN, but still every space is replaced by "NaN".

Would be really appreciated if someone could give me tips

After all, I would like to analyse each column such as percentage of "NaN" etc.

Thank you!

Comment: That's because the delimiter is `;` so why do you specify it as `,`? It's not a case of the file needing cleaning, `;` is perfectly valid as a delimiter

Comment: Hello what kind of dataset you’ve? csv I guess. Why not to use simply pandas. See documentation on pandas.read_csv()

Comment: I think he is under the assumption that specifying `delimiter=","` means "transform the existing delimiter, _whatever it may be_, into a comma".  Obviously it doesn't mean that.

Comment: @abdoulsn because that's a giant dependency to do a task that is already fully covered by a builtin library and the issue is that they're using the library incorrectly. The solution is not to just pull out a bazooka to fix a problem that's your own making

Comment: Hello I tried to use pandas but some of data are not read because of errors "b'Skipping line 3: expected 1 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 5: expected 1 fields"....the data contains special characters such as Russian, Japanese and so on. I am not sure if it matters for using pandas...but with csv reader it read everything...

Comment: Ok I get it. Handcrafted is super

Comment: @abdoulsn You don't need to go entirely "handcrafted" either. Python comes with a `csv` module that suffices for the purposes here.

Comment: @Sat could you detail your problem pleas. Merci

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result that you want by:

- specifying ';' as the delimiter when constructing a reader object
- passing each row through a function that converts empty cells to 'NaN' (or some other value of your choice)

Here is some sample code:

```
import csv 


def row_factory(row):
    return [x if x != '' else 'NaN' for x in row]


with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row_factory(row))
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'Product', 'Sales', 'Country', 'Website']
['NaN', 'Milk', '30', 'Germany', 'something.com']
['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'USA', 'NaN']
['Chris', 'Milk', '40', 'NaN', 'NaN']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct delimiter:

```
read_file = reader(opened_file, delimiter=";")
```

Your CSV file appears to be using a semicolon rather than a comma, so you need to tell `reader()` what to use.

**Tip:**

```
filename = open_dataset(filename)
```

Don't reassign a variable to mean something else. Before this line executes, `filename` is a string with the name of the file to open. After this assignment, `filename` is now a list of rows from the file. Use a different variable name instead:

```
rows = open_dataset(filename)
```

Now the two variables are distinct and their meaning is clear from the names. Of course, feel free to use something other than `rows` other than `filename`.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into using pandas. It can make data processing a lot easier, up to and including reading multi file formats.

if you want to read a csv:

```
import pandas as pd:
    my_file = '/pat/to/my_csv.csv'
    pd.read_csv(my_file)
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because your lists contain only one element, and that element is a single string, in order to parse a string into a list you can split it.

This should do what you need:

```py
for row in filename:
  parsed_row = row[0].split(';')
  for i in range(0, len(parsed_row)):
    if parsed_row[i] == '':
      parsed_row[i] = None
  print(parsed_row)
```

I made you a [Repl.it example](https://repl.it/repls/IllegalMiniatureApplescript)

Comment: This is really not good advice. The OP should switch their `csv` module to use the correct delimiter. This will break on any cell that happens to contain text with a semi-colon in it

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the line "parsed_row = row[0].split(';')"? as some lines are split into 2 lines somehow?

Comment: @Sat You should stick with using the CSV package as in your original code. Trying to call `split()` manually has several pitfalls.